# Migrating SD from Raspberry 1 B+ to Raspberry 2 microSD

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, pi-2

I have and old Raspberry 1 B+ with a normal SD card (60 GB), then I purchased a new Raspberry 2 with a 60 GB microSD card. I have followed [this tutorial](http://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/16982376-updating-raspbian-on-your-microsd-for-the-raspberry-pi-2) to completely migrate the Raspbian OS and its data to the new microSD card, but doesn´t cover my needs since I have one microSD, and one normal SD.

The other problem is that, according to one partition software, the old SD card has 60.00 GB, and the new microSD has 58.24, so I can not create an ISO file and replace it using Win32 Disk Imager (it says that it has not enough space).

Comment: Why not compact the old SD card image?  E.g. http://gparted.org/

Comment: I did´t know about the **compact** feature of gparted, sounds interesting. Can you provide more details of how it would be done?

Comment: It's a fairly simple graphical interface.  Select the SD card partition and then choose Partition->Resize/Move.

Answer (score 1):

it's simple : you can use [GParted](http://gparted.org) to shrink your original SD card's main partition, then ISO -> WinIMAGE as usual.