# upgrade pi2 to pi3 without reinstalling?

Tags: pi-3, pi-2, openhab

I want to upgrade my rpi2 to a rpi3. I'm running openHabian with a zwave gateway (razberry2).

Do I have to reinstall everything to be shure everything is fine or should the old setup work without problems?

Clarification: Can i simply switch the SD card and everything is fine?

Comment: You can't upgrade a Pi2 to a Pi3 that is a hardware change. Do you mean can you take the SD card from a Pi2 running openHabian and put it into a Pi3 and have it work?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer myself:
Have a look here: 
[Raspbian migration from Raspberry Pi 2 to Raspberry Pi 3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44232/raspbian-migration-from-raspberry-pi-2-to-raspberry-pi-3?rq=1)

This explains the DOs and DONTs

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please note that answers should provide context with links for reference only. If you think that the linked Q&A fully addresses this question here it is a duplicate to the other.